# Export events from the last X hours

Tags: event-log, event-viewer

I'm trying to diagnostic a strange behavior of a Windows system in which non-critical hardware (wireless+bt adapter, usb) freeze, but it seems to occur while the system is inactive for long periods of time. I need to check all logs between the time I know it to be working and now, for which I would like to export the events to a powerful system. How to export events between two specific points of time?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a "Custom filter", and set the "Logged" option, which allows several alternatives to filter events by date, and there are other options for type, user, etc.

After you create the filter as you like, you can export all events on said filter.